# view script doesn't recognizing view helpers in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, view-helpers

my problem is fairly when I call a view helper from view script it can't be called
although I added  properly all information path to the config file via this line:

```
resources.view.helperPath.ZF_View_Helper_="ZF/View/Helper/"
```

also I registered the helper in bootstrap file

```
function _initViewHelpers(){
    $view = new Zend_View();    
    $view->addHelperPath('ZF/View/Helper','ZF_View_Helper');
    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
}
```

but in vain it still printing out this error message:

```
Application error
Exception information:
Message: Plugin by name 'OutputHelper' was not found in the registry; used paths: 
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/
```

it doesn't include the custom view helper path as expected ;

the path of the  view helper is: library/ZF/View/Helper/OutputHelper.php

Comment: You are breaking the naming scheme of Zend Framework by renaming the Zend folder to ZF. This may cause problems in other places within the application as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you do this:

in view script

```
$view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('view');
var_dump($this === $view);
var_dump($view->getHelperPaths());
exit;
```

I think your view instance are replaced at some point.
May be module's bootstrap have view resource?

Or it can be other obvious mistake. So obvious so you'll never think of it

btw remove that _initViewHelpers method. Zend_Application_Resource_View work just fine for that.
And if you use this method, use it correctly, eg:

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
//whatever
```

Comment: Indeed. Sounds like the `Zend_View` instance is being replaced at some point.

Comment: thnks that was exactly as you said i  mistakely created new instance in controller action that i replaced now with:Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('view');   But now a new problem when i remove the _initViewHelper function as you said all custom view Helpers in the main Layout is not recognized again

Comment: @user796767 More convenient way to get view instance is `$view = Zend_Conroller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->getView();`